# determinant of the ordered exponential if $A$ is traceless matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, differential-geometry

Compute $det(OE[A](t))$ with $tr(A)=0$, where $OE[A]$ is defined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_exponential).

Attempt: First I computed the following derivative $\frac{d}{dt}det(OE[A](t))=tr((OE[A])^{-1}\frac{d}{dt}OE[A])det(OE[A](t))$. Since the ordered exponential can be written as a product of infinitesimal exponentials, I can use the product rule and simplify:
$tr((OE[A])^{-1}\frac{d}{dt}OE[A])=tr(\Delta t \sum_{i=1}^\infty A(t_i))=\Delta t \sum_{i=1}^\infty tr(A(t_i))=0$. Hence the determinant is independent on the parameter $t$ and now I choose $t=0$ (it's arbitrary) and get $det(OE[A](t))=1$.

Are there built errors? Are there formulas for the determinant of a ordered exponentials?
Hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt}OE[A] = \frac{d}{dt}\prod_{i=1}^N (1+ \Delta t A(it/N)) = N^{-1} \sum_{j=1}^N \prod_{i=1,i <j}^N (1+ \Delta t A(it/N)) \Delta t j A'(\frac{it}{N}) \times \prod_{i=1,i >j}^N (1+\Delta tA(it/N))$

Comment: Now I can multiply with the inverse of $OE[A]$ / take the trace and use properties of the trace. Also I repect only contributions linear in $\Delta t$. Since it holds also $tr(A'(\frac{it}{N}))=0$, the whole time derivative vanishes. Am I right?